# Does Apple iOS supports backward compatability?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

Hi does Apples iOS is having backward compatability? I'm having a doubt like in iOS 6 apple is introducing many new features like say for an example we have UICollectionView (for Grid) if i use this class & control of iOS6 then is there any flags or settings change or any extra code snippet available for developers so as to support iOS<6 also.

Comment: There is an "iOS Deployment Target" setting in Xcode - is that what you're asking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check `UICollectionView's` class availability  with [NSClassFromString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSClassFromString) function.

A simple example of Twitter :

```
Class TWTweetComposeViewControllerClass = NSClassFromString(@"TWTweetComposeViewController"); 

if (TWTweetComposeViewControllerClass != nil) 
{
     // this class only available in iOS 5
     // so new code
}
else
{
     // Means older version
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I found [some thing](https://github.com/AalokParikh/PSTCollectionView) similar to UICollectionView of iOS6 which is working on iOS4.3+ you have to find out or create this type of controls and use them in conditional coding as described in above answers.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

you definitely need to do conditional coding keeping in mind the available apis on ios version on device which is running the app